Jupyter Notebook not Starting in Virtual Environment
Environment

Ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.8.10
Pip 20.0.2

Using pip venv to create a virtual environment in my project directory. These are the commands I am running.
python3 -m pip venv .venv # Create the virtual environment
source .venv/bin/activate 
(.venv) $ time python3 -m pip install --requirement pip_requirements.txt # Inside the venv

My pip_requirements.txt has the following dependencies listed (among others)
jupyterlab
jupyter
notebook
ipython
ipykernel

So when I try to run jupyter notebook inside the venv, this is the error I get.
(.venv) della@workstation:~/Python_scripts/email-classification$  jupyter-notebook
(.venv) della@workstation:~/Python_scripts/email-classification$  jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/della/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.app import main
  File "/home/della/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/app.py", line 20, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.commands import (  # type:ignore[import-untyped]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterlab'

Tried with both space and hyphen in jupyter notebook and I get the same result.
When I look at the path, I see two things happening the interpreter is going outside the venv to look for the executable script. Should it happen at all when venv is meant to provide isolation? How can I run jupyter inside the venv with packages available only in the venv?
More information. When I try to see the executable for jupyter, I get one inside the venv.
(.venv) della@workstation:~/Python_scripts/email-classification$ which jupyter notebook -a
/home/della/Python_scripts/email-classification/.venv/bin/jupyter



"venv is meant to provide isolation?" Python virtual environments are not containers nor virtual machines. They provide isolation for Python packages but not full system isolation. If you run a script from outside of an venv the script uses python outside of the venv, and that python uses its own libraries, not from the venv. I already explained that to you, remember?

What happens if you run /home/della/Python_scripts/email-classification/.venv/bin/jupyter notebook?

You ought to run jupyter notebook, with a space, not hyphen.

Tried both, same result. Added more information in the original question.

I have tried the below steps and it is working for me,

Install venv:
python3 -m venv .venv   (try to create venv using this command)

Install pip_requirements.txt :
time python3 -m pip install --requirement pip_requirements.txt

running this command:
jupyter-notebook or  jupyter notebook both working for me


and also you can check this documentation also: https://jupyter.org/install
